# how to select records from two columns where one column consist word from second column?

Tags: postgresql, query

In postgres I want to select rows where column1 matches column2 for corresponding row and returns result having same values as well as records consisting word from column1.

```
select * from table_name where "column1" ILIKE "column2";
```

i am using above query but it returns exact matches, it should also return rows consisting words from column1 in column2.

```
column1 | column2
hello   | hello
please  | please guys
help    | help me
query   | website
```

my above query returns

```
column1
hello
```

i want it to return

```
column1
hello
please
help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need it to be case sensitive? If not try using `LIKE`

```
Create Table #Test
(
ColA Varchar(100)
,ColB Varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #Test
Values ('TEST', 'THIS IS A TEST')
,('String', 'This Also has word string in it')
,('ABC','DEF')
,('123','456')


Select      *
From        #Test 
Where       ColB Like '%' + ColA + '%'
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't accept `+`as a string concatenate operator. It also doesn't accept `#` as a table name character (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8ddd027710a26bbb645e2a1ccb04a349)).

Comment: thanks, pix1958, I used " || " instead of " + "

Answer (score 0):

select * from table_name where "column1" ILIKE '%'||"column2"||'%';

pix1985 got close. Replace + with two pipes.